# Change a color in Powerlevel10k

Tags: zsh

How can I change the directories colors that appears as options for the autocomplete in zsh Powerlevel10k ?
As you can see in the image they don't really stand out very well with a dark background color.

I've tried to dig in the `.oh-my-zsh/custom/themes/powerlevel10k/config` but to no avail.

[image: myzsh]

Comment: Powerlevel10k does not affect these colors. You can verify this by disabling Powerlevel10k. See https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/blob/master/README.md#which-aspects-of-shell-and-terminal-does-powerlevel10k-affect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Roman's answer, and after finding this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94299/dircolors-modify-color-settings-globaly) (so this question might be a duplicate) I have simply:

1. Created a `~/.dircolors` (could be any path you'd like) file and copied the standard LS colors to it by doing

`dircolors --print-database > ~/.dircolors`

2. Found the line that deal with the directories' LS color and changed it (of course you can change to any color you'd like), i.e.

`DIR 01;34`

To this:

`DIR 01;36`

3. Sourced the new `.dircolors` file in my `.zshrc` by adding:

```
d=~/.dircolors
test -r $d && eval "$(dircolors $d)"
```

Answer (score 1):

From their official docs, https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/blob/master/README.md#directory-is-difficult-to-see-in-prompt-when-using-rainbow-style.

```
for i in {0..255}; do print -Pn "%K{$i}  %k%F{$i}${(l:3::0:)i}%f " ${${(M)$((i%6)):#3}:+$'\n'}; done
```

Execute this in your terminal to see the color code as well.